# Automatically convert currencies and metrics from a text in PHP

Tags: php, type-conversion

I have a text like this

```
$text="The tower is 94.5m high, 
       the view is up to 100km. 
       The entrance is 8€";
```

Now I want to provide the tooltip for each metrics or currencies to get the result like this:

```
$text="The tower is <abbr title="310ft">94.5m</a> high, 
       the view is up to <abbr title="62mi">100km</abbr>. 
       The entrance is <abbr title="10USD">8€</abbr>
```

Some nice PHP function to convert these numbers automatically within the text? Thanks.

**edit**

To make this example simple, let's suppose we have fix rates everywhere. The question is, what kind of preg_replace or whatever to use... I used only something like this

```
preg_replace("/(.*)€/", $1*1.2, $text)
```

that is just an example how I was expecting to make it work, but of course it is not. :)

Comment: Most of those conversions are a simple multiplication or division, and you can find conversion tables in many places. Conversion between currencies will vary on an almost daily basis, so that's harder. But what have you tried, or are you just hoping somebody will do it for you?

Comment: No Mark totally don't want anybody do it for me, I just hope for an advice, how can I use the preg_replace or what way are these conversions done. Thank you.

Comment: Stop asking your homework questions here, naughty naughty.

Comment: please, this is not a homework, I have real problems AUTOMATICALLY converting metrics INSIDE the input text to get the formated result. This is not just a 1*2=2...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following:

```
$text="The tower is 94.5m high,  
       the view is up to 100km.  
       The entrance is 8€";

$result = preg_replace_callback("/(([0-9\.]+)(k?m))/", 'fn', $text);

var_dump($result);

function fn($matches) {
    switch($matches[3]) {
        case 'm' :
            // m to feet
            $conversion = $matches[2] * 3.28;
            $conversionUOM = 'ft';
            break;
        case 'km' :
            // km to miles
            $conversion = $matches[2] * 0.6;
            $conversionUOM = 'miles';
            break;
    }
    return '<abbr title="'.$conversion.$conversionUOM.'">'.$matches[0].'</abbr>';
}
```

You'll need to adjust the regexp and write additional cases for any other UOM conversion units you're likely to need, and use the correct figures in the actual conversions (I just used quick and dirty values), and any formatting of the numbers too... but it should give you the basis.

Answer (score 2):

There's no built-in PHP function that will automatically do conversion between different unit types. You'll have to do it yourself with the appropriate conversion rates.

Comment: If you're looking for the rates, you should just Google for that. You can search for "1 foot in meters".

Comment: We should not concentrate on the numbers and rates, I am searching for the answer HOW to use preg_replace or something to work with the variables.

Comment: What do you mean, use preg_replace? Can you give a specific example of what you want converted to what?

Comment: Yes, I just updated the question, please see there what I was expecting how it should work. Thx

Comment: preg_replace_callback() would be the more appropriate function, identify the values/units and use the callback to calculate the conversions

Comment: thanx very much, this is what i was asking for :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your own functions to do this. You do this in PHP like the following:

```
function meters_in_feet($meters)
{
    return $meters*3.28; // source: Google
}
```

Then you need to call it like:

```
$height_meters = 94.5;
$height_feet = meters_in_feet($height_meters);
```

Then:

```
echo '<abbr title="'.$height_feet.'">'.$height_meters.'m</a> high.';
```

This smells like a homework question, though, so as for getting the measurements etc out of an input text string which is probably what you're being asked to do, that's an exercise for the reader. ;)

Comment: exactly, i try to do the automatic conversions inside the input text and that is hard for me :)

Comment: Well if it's not hard it's not worth doing :)